# Oracle list partition table max value entries

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am partitioning a table in Oracle 11g using a list partition. The list partition is based upon an arbitrary id which we are grouping.

For instance:

```
PARTITION BY LIST (id)
( PARTITION 1 VALUES (2345,7433,3857,2457,5757,3204) TABLESPACE T1
```

What is the maximum values that the partition values can take. Ie can 2345,7433,3857,2457,5757,3204 be extended infinitely or what is the max?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_7002.htm#BABDGHIB):

> The string comprising the list of values for each partition can be up to 4K bytes. The total number of values for all partitions cannot exceed 64K-1.

So there is no specific limit on the number of values in a single partition, as long as they fit into the 4K restriction - which you'd obviously hit before the overall 64K-1 limit.

(If you're grouping the IDs arbitrarily - which isn't quite what you said - then [hash partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/partition.htm#i462869) might be simpler that maintaining the value lists. Depends what you're actually doing though, and why.)

Comment: Thanks that's great

Not quite as simple as a hash - this will be secondary. We need to group id's based on other attributes.